# push form entries from contact form directly into affiliate signup form (wp-plugin) using js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

ok so we have the following situation:

our potential customers make a trial account signup using contact form on our wordpress homepage. now we pretty much want to make every new trial-user, an affiliate at the same time.

there are a bunch of different wp-plugins to managae affiliates.

my q:

is it possible to send the form entries (from the trial signup) directly to the affiliate signup as well (and submit that in the background)?

because then the user would get one conf. mail with his trial account details from our backend & a 2nd email with his affiliate tracking link and some info on how that works.

thanks guys

Comment: Is this a custom contact form or plugin? What does your php and js code look like?